# Split a binary file into chunks c++

Tags: c++, parsing, file-io

I've been bashing my head against trying to first divide up a file into chunks, for the purpose of sending over sockets. I can read / write a file easily without splitting it into chunks. The code below runs, works, kinda. It will write a textfile and has a garbage character. Which if this was just for txt, no problem. Jpegs aren't working with said garbage.

Been at it for a few days, so I've done my research, and it's time to get some help. I do want to stick strictly to binary readers, as this need to handle any file.

I've seen a lot of slick examples out there. (none of them worked for me with jpgs) Mostly something along the lines of while(file)... I subscribe to the, if you know the size, use a for-loop, not a while-loop camp.

Thank you for the help!!

```
vector<char*> readFile(const char* fn){
    vector<char*> v;
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    char * memblock;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fn,ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()) {
        size = fileS(fn);
        file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
        int bs = size/3; // arbitrary. Actual program will use the socket send size
        int ws = 0;
        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < size; i+=bs){
            if(i+bs > size)
                ws = size%bs;
            else
                ws = bs;
            memblock = new char [ws];
            file.read (memblock, ws);
            v.push_back(memblock);
        }
    }
    else{
        exit(-4);
    }
    return v;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector<char*> v = readFile("foo.txt");
    ofstream myFile ("bar.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(vector<char*>::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it ){
        myFile.write(*it,strlen(*it));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you must also open the input file in binary mode.

Comment: Stylistically, since you're working with binary data, I would chose `uint8` or `unsigned char` over char*.

Comment: I'd also consider using a vector of vectors, as far as that goes. ditch that 'new char' and use your STL.

Comment: the vector is fine. I print it out as I go and they aren't the issue.

Comment: As far as I can tell I am opening the file and writing the file in binary mode. ofstream myFile ("out.txt", ios::out | ios::binary); file.open(fn,ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);

Comment: Another issue is that your solution isn't going to work when you actually send it over the wire. I'm assuming by socket, you're going to use TCP, but even if you choose a datagram protocol, you'll need to send along the size of the chunks first.

You're using strlen here, and it's a bit of a hack (also are you sure your memory block is null terminated in the right spot?)

since you know the size of the chunks (size/3) why not have your method set the chunk size, so you can use that later in your code, instead of recalculating it each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should never do this:

```
    myFile.write(*it,strlen(*it));
```

on binary data. `strlen` counts bytes until it hits a byte which contains a 0 (`NUL` as we like to say, but it's an honest 0). If you read enough binary data, you will hit a NUL, and you'll get a short count. But actually the situation could be a lot worse, because nowhere do you store the NUL for strlen to find. You're just counting on there being one beyond the end of the datablock you acquire to read the file into.

So don't do that. Remember the number of bytes in each block (you could use a vector> but there are a lot of more C++-like possibilities) and use that to write the data.

Comment: Of course. That makes sense. I was very confused to why I was getting smaller than the file reads.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are using a strlen to calculate the size of array to be written. A 0 to be a part of binary there you would not be writing the right size. Instead, use a pair of char*,int where int specifies the size that is to be written and you will be golden.
Like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;

ifstream::pos_type fileS(const char* fn)
{
    ifstream file;
        file.open(fn,ios::in|ios::binary);
    file.seekg(0, ios::end);
    ifstream::pos_type ret= file.tellg();
    file.seekg(0,ios::beg);
    ret=ret-file.tellg();
    file.close();
    return ret;
}

vector< pair<char*,int> > readFile(const char* fn){
    vector< pair<char*,int> > v;
    ifstream::pos_type size;
    char * memblock;
    ifstream file;
    file.open(fn,ios::in|ios::binary|ios::ate);
    if (file.is_open()) {
    size = fileS(fn);
    file.seekg (0, ios::beg);
    int bs = size/3; // arbitrary. Actual program will use the socket send size
    int ws = 0;
    int i = 0;
    cout<<"size:"<<size<<" bs:"<<bs<<endl;
    for(i = 0; i < size; i+=bs){
        if(i+bs > size)
            ws = size%bs;
        else
            ws = bs;
        cout<<"read:"<<ws<<endl;
        memblock = new char [ws];
        file.read (memblock, ws);
        v.push_back(make_pair(memblock,ws));
    }
    }
    else{
    exit(-4);
    }
    return v;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    vector< pair<char*,int> > v = readFile("a.png");
    ofstream myFile ("out.png", ios::out | ios::binary);
    for(vector< pair<char*,int> >::iterator it = v.begin(); it!=v.end(); ++it ){
    pair<char*,int> p=*it;
    myFile.write(p.first,p.second);
    }
}
```

Comment: I completely forgot c++ could use vector pairs. This worked perfectly! Now to see what happens when I send it over a socket! Seriously thank you I've been stuck on this for way too long. I really like the return to fileS.

Comment: instead of fileS, perhaps you could use boost -- example : 

cout << "filesize: " << boost::filesystem::file_size(fn);

Answer (score 1):

```
 myFile.write(*it,strlen(*it));
```

Is using string length on binary data. I suspect that is your culprit. If not, it's certainly a [code-smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).